# make inner divs scrollable in a lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css

I am developing a lightning component to drag-and-drop some items. It is called from a quick action on a record detail page. What I have noticed is that if the divs inside of it are too large, the entire component will start scrolling. What I want is that left-hand side and a right-hand sides scroll separately.

Screenshot:

[image]

When it's viewed on a large enough screen(or with low amount of items) it is fine. However, when the screen size changes:

[image]

I am not able to drag the "Fwd: Shizzle" onto "Other" anymore.

Code:

```
<aura:component description="MyLightningPopup" implements="force:lightningQuickAction,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" controller="MyApexController">
    <aura:attribute name="contentDocuments" type="ContentDocument[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="fileWraps" type="MyApexController.FilesWrapper[]" default="[]"/>

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
        <!-- Left hand side -->
        <div class="slds-size--1-of-2">
            <section class="accordion">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.contentDocuments}" var="obj">
                    <div id="{!obj.Id}" draggable="true" ondragstart="{!c.drag}">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="accordion-role" id="{!obj.Id + '_rad'}" />
                        <label for="{!obj.Id + '_rad'}">
                            <lightning:button label="Delete" variant="destructive" onclick="{!c.handleDeleteRecord}" value="{!obj.Id}"/> {!obj.Title}
                        </label>
                        <article>
                            <lightning:fileCard fileId="{!obj.Id}"/>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                    <br/><br/>
                </aura:iteration>
            </section>
        </div>
        <!-- Right hand side -->
        <div class="slds-size--1-of-2" align="center" id="dropzone">
            <section class="accordion">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.fileWraps}" var="obj">
                    <div id="{!obj.fileId == null ? obj.fileName : obj.fileId}" draggable="{!obj.fileId == null ? false : true}" ondragstart="{!c.drag}" ondrop="{!c.drop}" ondragover="{!obj.fileId == null ? c.allowDrop : c.doNothing}">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="accordion-role" id="{!obj.fileName + '_rad'}" disabled="{!obj.fileId == null || obj.fileId == ''}" />
                        <label for="{!obj.fileName + '_rad'}">
                            {!obj.fileName}
                        </label>
                        <article>
                            <lightning:fileCard fileId="{!obj.fileId}"/>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                    <br/><br/>
                </aura:iteration>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Salesforce Lightning Design System has a tag built in for just this purpose. You should be able to add the .slds-scrollable_y class to your divs that hold the left hand side and the right hand side. You may need to also set the height of those divs to a fixed height.

Documentation on the scrollable classes [can be found here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/scrollable/).

As mentioned by sfdcfox in the comments, you can also use the [ui:scrollerWrapper](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/ui:scrollerWrapper/documentation) component instead of writing the css yourself. One cool benefit of that component that isn't really applicable in this use-case is that it has a 'scrollTo' method that let's you scroll the content to a specific location.

Comment: Alternatively, ui:scrollerWrapper.

Answer (score 3):

You can try applying [.slds-scrollable_y](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/scrollable/) CSS to each of the two  divs as they currently are, but I'm not certain that will provide the results that you're looking for.

I strongly suspect the way to achieve what you're asking is to put the Left and Right parts of your component into separate containers (apply the .slds-scrollable_y to each of them) that have their own accordions and then wrap them inside an outer component.  That should definitely allow you to scroll the left component and the right component independently.